# Bootstrap Height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I'm new in Bootstrap and I was wondering if I can make a menu to take the full height in lg and md desktop? And how can I do that? Also the  menu is an `ul` and it has 3 `li` elements and I want them to have equal height.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Though you'll need to provide your **existing code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is) in order for us to really be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height using ‘vh’ units in css. 100vh is the height of the viewport, so divide that up as needed.